# Why is my water well tank staying at a constant 40psi even when faucets are turned on?

Tags: water, water-pressure, well-pump

I have a older style bladder tank that is about 6ft tall. Pressure gauge always reads 40psi, it never gets above or below 40psi. The pressure switch never kicks on or off because the pressure never drops. Pressure in house is good excepts every so often there is lots of air in hot water line.

Comment: *The pressure switch never kicks on or off* so is it constantly **on**, or constantly **off?** Does the water stop if you turn off the breaker supplying the pump? There are several possibilities to sort between, here.

Comment: Yes the water stops if there is no power to it. The pressure gauge on the tank broke last year so i replaced it ..so gauge is good.the pressure switch works, because i can shut water off from the switch. i guess it would have to be constantly on since i have water because if it was off i would have no water right?...Im a plumber and no very little about water wells.

Comment: Sounds like option 3, then. Time for a new pump, most likely - or at least a consultation with someone who does know about water wells, and pumps. Should cut your power bill, but will probably cost a good deal to get there. You should [edit] those details into your question...

Comment: What is the problem you are trying to fix? It doesn't sound like you have a problem, stuff is just working.

Answer (score 4):

Option 1: the well is uphill (about 92 feet vertically) and a pump is entirely optional.

Option 2: the well is textbook [artesian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artesian_aquifer), (water comes out the top under pressure equivalent to being 92 feet uphill, unless a pressure seal is in place) and a pump is entirely optional.

**Option 3: the pump is running all the time, and is worn out, and can't make enough pressure now to ever turn the pressure switch off. Can't be doing your power bill any good.**

Option 3a: There's a leak in the pipe from the pump to the house. If the pump is submersible and the leak is in the part of the pipe inside the well, you would not see a wet spot, but you'd be pumping water in circles. If the leak is the right size, it might be holding your pump from ever getting above 40 PSI (But I consider worn out pump more likely, usually.)

Option 4: the pressure gauge is broken and stuck at 40, but "pressure in house is good" trends away from that.

Comment: I'm totally agreeing with 3, the pump is simply worn out and running all the time, it can't build enough pressure for the pressure switch to turn off.   Ecnerwal, your other explanations are creative, but given the fact that the OP loses water when there is no power eliminates them as possible causes. If the OP has access to the wiring and an amp clamp, he could determine if it's running or not. ....probably is and like you said, this isn't doing his power bill any good!  +

Comment: The answer was written before the OP clarified. Bolding 3 and adding 3a came after that clarificaton.